# Wordpress: Where to Find Files Created from Templates of a theme?

Tags: wordpress, templates

Using wordpress: created a file from a template in a theme I was using. Now I want to edit something in that individual file. Which folder, or where or how do I find that document and edit it?

Note: I'm a novice at wordpress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit an individual page in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112009/how-do-i-edit-an-individual-page-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearance > Editor will allow you to edit the code of any of the files of your themes. If you want to edit the file using a more advanced editor, like a code editor, they are stored in wp-content/themes/your-theme replacing your-theme with the name of the theme.

Comment: So it seems that once a template is set and used for a new page, a component of that page IS the template, not a copy. That means I can't edit that individual page without changing the entire template format?  :-/

Comment: Are you talking about post templates or normal theme files? If you're just looking at post templates then you can copy the existing template you want to change into a new template and make the changes. Then you'll have the original, plus your new one with changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between post templates and theme files. I thought theme files contained post templates? 

You bring up a great solution, thanks.